# debugging openCV in visual studio 2005

Tags: c++, opencv, debugging

I am new to Visual Studio 2005 and am trying to get to grips with it. I am using it to compile and debug an application called AAM-library (which I didn't write) which uses OpenCV 1.0. I have compiled the software and now I'm getting a runtime error.

To figure out the reason for the error (I know the line number and file name that generates the error, since the runtime error tells me) I want to step through the code in the few lines before the error. The error is in an openCV file called opencv/cv/src/cvshapedescr.cpp. To debug I have figured out that I can step through from the start of the program using F11 or F10 but this is taking forever to reach the error. Is there a way to get straight to the error? I'm trying to put a breakpoint in the openCV file, but this is not part of the workspace that I am working on, and so it doesn't seem to be having an effect.

Comment: OpenCV is already on version 2.2. Version 1.0 is ancient and should not be used. Use version 2.0 if you can as is stated on the homepage of aam-library: http://code.google.com/p/aam-library/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place a breakpoint a few lines before the error or use run to cursor. There is no magical "10 lines before this breakpoint" feature. (Intellitrace can do this for managed code but that's a whole different ballgame)

Also note that concurrent debugging was made a LOT better in VC2008, you might want to consider using a more recent compiler, such as VC2008 or VC2010.

Comment: Hi,

Many thanks for your reply. Here is what I've tried:

I run from the command line: 
>devenv /debugexe buildD -t 0 -p 3 ../image jpg pts haarcascade_frontalface_alt2.xml model1

("buildD -t 0 -p 3 ../image jpg pts haarcascade_frontalface_alt2.xml model1" is what generates my error)

This opens a new instance of VC2005 and I step through the code using F11. But this takes forever to get to the problem. So, instead, I tried to open the problem file, and put a breakpoint in, but it says "The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document".

Comment: @Andrew: Then you need to put the symbols where VS can get to them. (Which probably means building both your code and OpenCV in debug mode too)